# Add column name with COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I have this stored procedure, and I want to add a column name to the value I'm getting. Where should I add the

> as "TotalNewspapers"

(or whatever I have to add) if Im using the **COALESCE**?

```
SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT 
  count(distinct Appendage.AppendageName) as "TotalNewspapers" 
  FROM Edition
   inner join SourceInformation on (SourceInformation.SourceInformationID =  Edition.SourceInformationID)
   left join Appendage on (Appendage.AppendageID = Edition.AppendageID)
   inner join Pages on (Edition.EditionID = Pages.EditionID)
  where 
    Edition.publishdate >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    and Edition.publishdate <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)+1 
    and Pages.PullBy is null
    and Edition.FinishDate is null
group by Appendage.AppendageName, SourceInformation.SourceInformationName, Pages.PullBy, Edition.FinishDate, Appendage.AppendageID
having count(Pages.PullBy) > 1) , 0);
```

Comment: You want to give the result of the `COALESCE()` an alias, so just put `as "TotalNewpapers"` after the `COALESCE((subquery), 0)`.

Comment: Great! Thanks! That works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
SELECT ISNULL(( --OR COALESCE
    SELECT count(distinct a.AppendageName) as [TotalNewspapers]
    FROM Edition e
    inner join SourceInformation s
        on (s.SourceInformationID =  e.SourceInformationID)
    left join Appendage a
        on (a.AppendageID = e.AppendageID)
    inner join Pages p
        on (e.EditionID = p.EditionID)
    where 
        e.publishdate >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        and e.publishdate <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)+1 
        and p.PullBy is null
        and e.FinishDate is null
    group by a.AppendageName, s.SourceInformationName, p.PullBy, e.FinishDate, a.AppendageID
    having count(p.PullBy) > 1
),0) as [TotalNewspapers]
```

I remove sub-query, all you need can be done in one select statement. Also add [aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to get 0 if the value is null as well.

Comment: Have you tried it? :) `ISNULL` will replace NULL with the specified replacement value (in our case it is 0). `COALESCE` evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL. So if `count(distinct a.AppendageName)` will be NULL it will choose next value which is 0.

Comment: I did. And the value is still null, is not writing 0 instead

Comment: Changed answer, please check.

Comment: There is only one situation where I'd recommend `ISNULL` over `COALESCE` (and that's to force a view's column definition to be marked as `not null` rather than `null`). Otherwise, I'd always `COALESCE` - it generalises to more than two inputs, it follows normal data type precedence rules and it's ANSI standard SQL. What reason do you have for preferring `ISNULL` here?

Comment: COALESCE is harder to spell though

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There is just one value that needs to be changed in `0` if it is `NULL` so I see no reasons to use ONLY `COALESCE`. Is there any reasons not to use `ISNULL` in that particular situation?